# De-Serialize custom Enum to its value

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

Lets say I have a custom enum

```
public sealed class Shape
{
    // enum values
    public static readonly Shape Circle = new Shape(100, "Circle");
    public static readonly Shape Square = new Shape(200, "Square");
    public static readonly Shape Rectangle = new Shape(300, "Rectangle");

    // enum value properties 
    public readonly short Number;
    public readonly string Name;

    // private constructor
    private Shape(short number, string name)
    {
        Number = number;
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

I want support newtonsoft JSON.Net serialization this way:

- `Shape.Circle` is serialized to `100`
- `100` is deserialized to `Shape.Circle`
- optionally, also string `"Circle"` is deserialized to `Shape.Circle`

Can I set logic for de/-serialization of this Enum object in the class, e.g. set implicit operator conversion from `int` and `string` or use some special JSON.Net attributes, properties? I want to have all logic contained in Enum object, so users will simply mark type as `Shape` and there will be no need for setting custom `convertors` or such.

Comment: Where is the `Enum`? It's a class with static public fields.

Comment: Why not having a Custom JsonConverter and assign it to the class with an attribute?

Comment: And also, does this class have any internal logic? why not use the native .net enum?

Comment: I would be concerned that some potentially critical logic (e.g. 100 = Circle)  is tied up in a serializer. If you ever needed another serializer you would have to replicate the logic. I would personally have a `ShapeFactory` class that accepts `Circle` or `100` or whatever comes out of JSON and responds accordingly with the correct type/instance. Then you can use the standard JSON serializer.